# how to configure apache ignite as cache api and as spring cache provider?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, ignite, spring-cache

I want to use ignite as cache api as well as spring cache provider. I am running following configuration in ignite-config.xml file as below

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd"
                        >

<!--    <bean id="cacheIgniteBean" class="org.apache.ignite.IgniteSpringBean">
   <property name="configuration">  -->


<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
  <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
  <property name="igniteInstanceName" value="claimgrid"/>
<property name="cacheConfiguration">
                <list>
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">

                        <property name="name" value="T_MST_TEUC_Q_PERCENTAGE"/>
                        <property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED"/>
                        <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                        <property name="partitionLossPolicy" value="READ_WRITE_SAFE"/>
                        <property name="backups" value="0"/>
                        <property name="groupName" value="masterData"/>
                        <property name="cacheStoreFactory">
                            <bean class="javax.cache.configuration.FactoryBuilder" factory-method="factoryOf">
                                <constructor-arg value="com.mrm.access.benefits.ms.claim.cache.store.SequesterPercentageModelStore"/>
                            </bean>

                        </property>

                        <property name="readThrough" value="true"/>
                        <property name="writeThrough" value="true"/>

                    </bean>
</list>
</property>



    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                 <property name="addresses">
                        <list>  
                              <value>10.80.211.76</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                    </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I am initializing the ignite node as below.

```
ApplicationContext context= SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
Ignite ignite=IgniteSpring.start("ignite-config.xml", context);
```

The node gets up and running. Now I am using second configuration file for spring cache manager spring-cache.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd"
                        >
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.apache.ignite.cache.spring.SpringCacheManager">



        <property name="igniteInstanceName" value="claimgrid" />


</bean>
<cache:annotation-driven/>
```

and I am initializing this file as below

```
Ignite ignite=Ignition.start("spring-cache.xml");
```

I am getting the below exception

```
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to find configuration in: file:/E:/Workspace/ms.claim/spring-cache.xml
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.loadConfigurations(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:116)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.loadConfigurations(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:98)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.loadConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:744)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:945)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:854)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:724)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:693)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:352)
    ... 2 more
```

While debugging the ignite source code I found that ignite internally uses `SpringHelper` to get the Spring Application Context and after that it tries to fetch `IgniteConfiguration` instance as spring bean using `getBeansOfType()` method in one of the classes and from there it does not get the configuration instance and throws the above exception.

As mentioned in the Ignite documentation I am using the same `gridName` or `instanceName` property in `SpringCacheManager` in `spring-cache.xml`.

Can somebody please check the issue? Also I am not sure I am following the correct method. First I am staring the ignite node with `ignite-config.xml` and `IgniteSpring.start` and once a node is up I am initializing `spring-cache.xml` with `Ignition.start` to configure `Ignite` as `SpringCacheManager`.

Answer (score 1):

This is also discussed on Apache Ignite user forum: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/how-to-configure-apache-ignite-as-cache-api-and-as-spring-cache-provider-td24068.html